# Python, Regular Expression, string to string with dots

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone help me with this:

Version 1:

```
import re
text = "12032020"
Version **ONE**
r = re.compile(r'\d{8}')
r1 = re.compile(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}')
output = re.sub(r, r1, text)
```

Version 2:

```
output1 = re.sub(r'\d{8}', r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})', text)
print(output)
```

I expect outcome:

```
12.03.2020
```

Not working

Comment: Please explain *why* you expect that outcome, and what you get instead.

Comment: I need that for change entire column in excel from strings into calendar data. I wanted to start using re insted of other ways. I am learning hot to post. So thank you for amending. Next time I would do the same way Scott :)

Comment: No, I meant why do you think this code should be correct?

Comment: Why even using a regular expression? something like `text[0:2]+'.'+text[2:4]+'.'+text[4:]` should work in your case!

Comment: I don't know if if r.match(text) it looks ok but the re.sub is not changing from one pattern to another. Instead I got exactly the same unformatted string (text) 12032020 (no dots)

Comment: Thank you B.Go. I simply want to learn regex and try something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing string substitution with:

```
(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})
```

Here would be an example from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TCuqkU/1):

[image]

Here you would capture each of the three groups (2-digit, 2-digit, 4-digit) and then re-insert those three captured strings with a dot between them. In python:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})', r'\1.\2.\3', '12032020')
'12.03.2020'
```

Though it looks like you're trying to parse a date so why not do:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(text, '%m%d%Y')
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 12, 0, 0)
```